# IMAP4_SSL with gmail in python

Tags: python, html, gmail

We are retrieving mails from our gmail account using IMAP4_SSL and python.
The email body is retrieved in html format.
We need to convert that to plaintext.
Can anyone help us with that?

Answer (score 2):

Stand on the shoulders of giants...
Peter Bengtsson has worked out a solution to this exact problem [here](http://www.peterbe.com/plog/html2plaintext).
Peter's script uses the awesome [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), by Leonard Richardson, 
and Fredrik Lundh's [unescape() function](http://effbot.org/zone/re-sub.htm).

Using Peter's test case, you get this:

```
This is a paragraph.

Foobar [1]
http://two.com

Visit http://www.google.com.

Text elsewhere. Elsewhere [2]

[1] http://one.com
[2] http://three.com
```

...from this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<body>

<div id="main">
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

<p><a href="http://one.com">Foobar</a>
<br />

<a href="http://two.com">two.com</a>

</p>
  <p>Visit <a href="http://www.google.com">www.google.com</a>.</p>
<br />
Text elsewhere.

<a href="http://three.com">Elsewhere</a>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```